# Duda mysql y phpmyadmin, error con función

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con mysql y phpmyadmin, a la hora de procesar esta función me marca un err

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fnFormatoDefaultInsertaBitacoraXml` (`_codUsuario` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin BEGIN
    DECLARE fechaHora VARCHAR(25);
    SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS VARCHAR(50))
    INTO fechaHora
    RETURN '<B><I fechaHora="' + fechaHora + '" codUsuario="' + cast(_codUsuario AS VARCHAR(10)) + '"/></B>';
END$$
```

Lanza este error:

1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'RETURN '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algunos puntos a revisar:

- [CAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast): Revisar los tipos permitidos (`CHAR`).
- Agregar `;` al final de la sentencia `SELECT`.
- Para concatenar texto, una opción es, usar la función [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION DEFINER='root'@'localhost' `fnFormatoDefaultInsertaBitacoraXml` (
  `_codUsuario` INT
) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
BEGIN
    DECLARE `fechaHora` VARCHAR(25);

 -- SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS VARCHAR(50))
    SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS CHAR(50))
 -- INTO `fechaHora`
    INTO `fechaHora`;

 -- RETURN '<B><I fechaHora="' + `fechaHora` + '" codUsuario="' + CAST(`_codUsuario` AS VARCHAR(10)) + '"/></B>';
    RETURN CONCAT('<B><I fechaHora="', `fechaHora`, '" codUsuario="', CAST(`_codUsuario` AS CHAR(10)), '"/></B>');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80a4181c04ecc4e9df67bf3759fb7029).